# Set title/icon etc to TabBarItem created in IB, through code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a TabBar that I've created through IB, I chose "create new project" -> "Tab bar application". Is there a way for me to access one of the TabBarItems for customization through the code?

It seems to me that something like:
`[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"Button one"];`
should set the title of that item to "Button one", but it doesen't. The title itself is not a problem (I can set that through IB aswell), however adding an Icon seems to be.

So to sum up, what I really want to know is: Is there a way to add an Icon to a TabBarItem created through IB?

**SOLUTION:**
Adding in viewDidLoad in the first view, being loaded automatically upon starting the app:

```
UITabBarController *tb = [self tabBarController];
[[tb.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"Title"];
```

Let me set the title of the second button (objectAtIndex: 1). I was also able to set the image the same way, which also worked for buttons one (objectAtIndex: 0) and three (objectAtIndex: 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your viewDidLoad: method of one of the tabBar viewControllers and it should work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //Get the tabBarItem
    UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];

    //Give it a lable
    [tbi setTitle:@"Title A"];

    //create a image from a file for the tabBar
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NiceImage.png"];
    //and put it on the tabBar
    [tbi setImage:i];

}
```

Comment: Braintiff, this works, however only once you click on the TabBarItem, and the view gets loaded. Before that there's no image :(

Comment: That is weird! I just tested this code with a new project and it works without the effect you just mentioned.

Comment: Wait! Solved it, I put that code in the second Item, that is; not the Item (and view) that is being loaded upon loading the app, therefore it didn't work. Putting the code in the first view however, let me access all of the other Items aswell. I'll edit my question and allaborate, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the image and title properties on the TabBarItems:

```
UITabBarItem *item = (UITabBarItem *)[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
item.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
```

Don't forget that the UITabBar only uses the alpha values out of the image you set, so if you don't have an alpha channel in the image you may not see anything when you set an image on the tab bar item.

Answer (score 0):

I've never created a tab bar through IB (always through code), however to set title and icon I use

```
controller.title = @"Controller";
controller.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

where `controller` is the `UIViewController` added to the `viewControllers`' array of the `UITabBarController`.

Comment: I will always create them in code from now on, so I don't encounter this problem again :P but right now I'd rather get this resolved then redo it in code.